# Spring не находит путь или я не так делаю?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Есть контроллер:

```
@RestController(value = "/api/") // Даже так "/api" не работает
public class ApiController {

    @Autowired
    private PeopleRepository peopleRepository;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(ApiController.class);

    @PostMapping(value = "/save")
    public Response save(Response response, @RequestBody People people) throws SQLException {

        LOGGER.info(people);

        if(peopleRepository.save(people)) {
            response.setSuccess("OK");
        } else {
            response.setError("Error");
        }

        return response;
    }

}
```

Я делаю запрос `http://localhost:8080/api/save` но в консоли сервера спринг мне пишет такое:

> ```
> No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/api/save] in DispatcherServlet
>     with name 'dispatcher'.
> ```

Разве не должно работать?

Настройка `DispatcherServlet`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package = "com.server.controller"/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="268435456"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

`web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

    <!--<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>-->

    <display-name>Server</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Логи сервера:

```
2018-06-29 20:11:47.113 [INFO] [thread-id 22] org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494) - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
2018-06-29 20:11:47.125 [INFO] [thread-id 22] org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:590) - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Fri Jun 29 20:11:47 EEST 2018]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
2018-06-29 20:11:47.126 [INFO] [thread-id 22] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:316) - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [dispatcher-servlet.xml]
2018-06-29 20:11:47.769 [INFO] [thread-id 22] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:547) - Mapped "{[/save],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json]}" onto public com.linkedin.people.parser.server.entity.Response com.linkedin.people.parser.server.controller.ApiController.save(com.server.entity.Response,com..server.entity.People) throws java.sql.SQLException
2018-06-29 20:11:47.772 [INFO] [thread-id 22] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:547) - Mapped "{[/ || /index]}" onto public java.lang.String com.linkedin.people.parser.server.controller.BaseController.index()
2018-06-29 20:11:48.493 [INFO] [thread-id 22] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.initControllerAdviceCache(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:574) - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Fri Jun 29 20:11:47 EEST 2018]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
2018-06-29 20:11:48.600 [INFO] [thread-id 22] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.initControllerAdviceCache(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:574) - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Fri Jun 29 20:11:47 EEST 2018]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
2018-06-29 20:11:48.677 [INFO] [thread-id 22] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:373) - Mapped URL path [/api] onto handler '/api'
2018-06-29 20:11:48.737 [INFO] [thread-id 22] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:373) - Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
2018-06-29 20:11:48.903 [INFO] [thread-id 22] org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:509) - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 1789 ms
```

Comment: Пробовали убрать последний слэш? @RestController(value = "/api")

Comment: @RomanDanilov пробовал - не работает. Изначально без него и было.

Comment: мне вот интересно. и за что -1 голос? ппц.... люди

Comment: А запрос вы как делаете? Через какую программу?

Comment: @RomanDanilov обычный ajax запрос.

Comment: Я просто к тому, что запрос должен быть POST обязательно, если просто открывать с браузера, то он его не найдет

Comment: @RomanDanilov запрос POST конечно же.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79573/discussion-between-roman-danilov-and-tsyklop).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я думаю у вас пропущена аннотация @RequestMapping

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
public class ApiController {
```

Comment: неа. Теперь запрос вообще перестал работать.

Comment: @Tsyklop так он же у вас и так не работал) В таком случае нужны данные о настройке DispatcherServlet, возможно там какой-нибудь префикс для запросов настроен. Как у вас настроен спринг, как он сканирует бины, попадает ли он вообще в контейнер. Но то, что у вас пропущена аннотация, это точно

Comment: Тогда он не работал но сообщение о том что маппинг не найден писалось. Сейчас же пустота. в AJAX вообще ошибка. Настройку приложил в шапке. 
Если я добавляю эту аннотацию то вообще ничего не работает, вообще. И в примерах я нигде не видел такого.

Comment: + еще нужно было настроить `Cors`.